# Output a video made of several video chunks of the input video

Tags: ffmpeg

I was wondering if it was possible to output a video made of several extracts of the input video.
For example outputting a video made of the first 10s of each minute of the input.

I know you can do it programmatically, calling `ffmpeg` several times with -ss and -t to make the chunks and then merge them, but is it possible to do it in one command using video filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved ! Here is the final solution:

Each first 2s of every minute, audio and video.

```
ffmpeg -i fullmovie.mp4 
-vf "select='gte(mod(t\,60),0)*lte(mod(t\,60),2)',setpts='N/(FRAME_RATE*TB)'" 
-vcodec libx264  -crf 23 -acodec libfaac -ac 1 -ab 56k 
-af "aselect='gte(mod(t\,60),0)*lte(mod(t\,60),2)',asetpts='N/(SAMPLE_RATE*TB)'" trailer.mp4
```

- select filters evaluates the expression for each input frame, it
  discards it if result is 0, and keeps it if result is 1
- my expression returns 1 for the first 2 seconds of each minute
- setpts modify the PTS of each frame/sample according to the number of
  the frame/sample and the framerate/samplerate

Answer (score 0):

No, at the moment this is not really possible. You would have to write a script that calls `ffmpeg` multiple times with the given `-ss` and `-t` options – at least that's the most straightforward way.

Don't forget that the position of `-ss` matters:

> When used as an input option (before -i), seeks in this input file to position. When used as an output option (before an output filename), decodes but discards input until the timestamps reach position. This is slower, but more accurate.

I would have said you could use the `select` filter, which allows you to have it evaluate expressions like "select only frames between 10 and 20 seconds", but I haven't got it to work without duplicating frames and producing the correct (i.e. cut) output.

Comment: thanks for the idea, i think I'm onto something I'll post it as answer